# python why doesnt str or repr or unicode get called when calling my_string.lower()

Tags: python

given this class

```
class Stringy(unicode):
    def __init__(self,something):
        self.something = something
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Stringy(%s)"%repr(self.something)
    def __str__(self):
        return "str(%s)"%repr(self.something)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "unicode(%s)"%repr(self.something)
```

running the following

```
s = Stringy("Hello")
print s.lower()  #prints "hello" !!! Why?
print s  # correctly prints str('Hello')
print unicode(s) #correctly prints unicode('Hello')
print [s]        #correctly prints Stringy('Hello')
print s.upper()  #prints "HELLO"  !!! Why?
```

why don't `upper`/`lower`/etc  trigger the `__str__` method?

shouldnt under the hood something like
`unicode(self).lower()` be happening ?

or `str(self).lower()` ?

Comment: don't forget that the object that you're inheriting from is typically `immutable` (methods return new instances of the original type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.lower` is calling `unicode.lower()`, so you get a new distinct unicode object

You'd need to have `lower()` method which returns a `Stringy` object

eg.

```
def lower(self):
    return Stringy(unicode.lower(self))
```

Comment: but shouldnt it be calling something like unicode(self).lower ? I dont do any super inits in the `__init__` ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley You don't override `lower` at all, so it goes straight for `unicode`'d implementation of it, which is neither written nor documented to return instances of subclasses.

Comment: @delnan:  He never initiates the superclass.  How does the superclass know to act on `self.something`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski It doesn't.

Comment: It still doesnt really make sense how passing self into unicode.lower gets "hello" just by itself ...

Answer (score 1):

Because a string is immutable, and calling `upper()` on it returns a *new* string. And your new string will be an actual `unicode` instance, not a `Stringy`.

Comment: Very important to note the immutability of Python string objects.

Answer (score 0):

The `print` doesn't trigger `Stringy.__str__()` because the result of `s.lower()` is a brand new object of type `unicode`:

```
In [3]: type(Stringy('').lower())
Out[3]: unicode
```